# Multiple words in any order using regex

Tags: regex

As the title says , I need to find two specific words in a sentence. But they can be in any order and any casing. How do I go about doing this using regex?

For example, I need to extract the words `test` and `long` from the following sentence whether the word `test` comes first or `long` comes.

```
This is a very long sentence used as a test
```

UPDATE:
What I did not mention in the first part is that it needs to be case insensitive as well.

Comment: Do you care about multiple occurrences of the words? Do you know what words you want to extract, or are you wanting to match words that fit a particular pattern? Do you want to find out what position they're at?

Comment: I know the exact words , dont car about multiples , dont need the position.

I do need to be case insensitive

Comment: Which regex flavor are you using? JavaScript, .NET, PHP...? And how important is performance? Are you working with very large strings, or doing a great many matches? Several viable answers have been posted already, but none of them is particularly efficient.

Comment: I think the most important thing (which i found out today) is that it is doing the checks in .Net , so i am not sure if all the answers below apply , i have tried all and sadly .net does not pick up any as case insensitive

Comment: Ehh, whether it's case sensitive or not should not be dependent on regex. You're better off with programming the software to be case insensitive.

However, to recognize multiple words in any order using regex, I'd suggest the use of **quantifier** in regex: `(\b(james|jack)\b.*){2,}`. Unlike **lookaround** or **mode modifier**, this works in most regex flavours.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use a capturing group if you want to extract the matches: `(test)|(long)`
Then depending on the language in use you can refer to the matched group using $1 and $2, for example.

Comment: I used this answer in conjunction with the (?i) from the answer below, This resulted in the following out put (?i)(test(long)?) because it turns out i had to test for test first  and then long. If it is the correct way is another story but it worked for me

Comment: Given the requirement is to match test AND long, this solution needs the g flag.

Answer (score 63):

You can use

```
(?=.*test)(?=.*long)
```

Source: [MySQL SELECT LIKE or REGEXP to match multiple words in one record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9099469/mysql-select-like-or-regexp-to-match-multiple-words-in-one-record)

Comment: This fails. https://regex101.com/r/Z8KOLp/2

Comment: @ChrisJJ the mentioned regexp does not return the words test or long. But it returns matches if it found the words test or long in any order and returns non matches if it doesn't.

Comment: Sure, but the requirement is to find/extract the words, not simply to test for them.

Comment: Another variant: [`(?is)^(?=.*\b(test)\b)(?=.*?\b(long)\b).*`](https://regex101.com/r/CPNu4y/1) which also captures the words and matches all string. Further anchored to `^` start which improves performance considerably. `\b` matches a *word boundary*.

Comment: is there any way to match any or both of these two words?. e.g.if used that regexp with the text "This is a very long sentence" , the long word will not be found. It would be good to add an optional modifier. Is it possible?

Comment: Ok for my previous comment i guess just \b(test)|\b(long) will be enough

Comment: If the answers regex is too slow, you can add ^ to the start of it to considerably increase performance as said in bobblebubble's answer.

Comment: MariaDB word boundaries are `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]`. So instead of `\b(test)\b` you do; `[[:<:]](test)[[:>:]]`

Answer (score 14):

I assume (always dangerous) that you want to find whole words, so "test" would match but "testy" would not. Thus the pattern must search for word boundaries, so I use the "\b" word boundary pattern.

```
/(?i)(\btest\b.*\blong\b|\blong\b.*\btest\b)/
```

Answer (score 9):

without knowing what language

```
 /test.*long/
```

or

```
/long.*test/
```

or

```
/test/ && /long/
```

Comment: I'd add word boundaries, e.g. `/\btest\b/`.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
/(?i)(?:test.*long|long.*test)/
```

That will match either `test` and then `long`, or `long` and then `test`. It will ignore case differences.

Comment: You don't need (?i) unless you want it to be case sensitive, but this works.

Answer (score 3):

Vim has a branch operator `\&` that allows an even terser regex when searching for a line containing any number of words, in any order.

For example,

`/.*test\&.*long`

will match a line containing `test` and `long`, in any order.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58694336/976728) for more information on usage.  I am not aware of any other regex flavor that implements branching; the operator is not even documented on the [Regular Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) wikipedia entry.

Answer (score 2):

I was using libpcre with C, where I could define callouts. They helped me to easily match not just words, but any subexpressions in any order. The regexp looks like:

```
(?C0)(expr1(?C1)|expr2(?C2)|...|exprn(?Cn)){n}
```

and the callout function guards that every subexpression is matched exactly once,like:

```
int mycallout(pcre_callout_block *b){
static int subexpr[255];
if(b->callout_number == 0){
    //callout (?C0) - clear all counts to 0
    memset(&subexpr,'\0',sizeof(subexpr));
    return 0;
}else{
    //if returns >0, match fails
    return subexpr[b->callout_number-1]++;
}
}
```

Something like that should be possible in perl as well.

Answer (score -9):

I don't think that you can do it with a single regex. You'll need to d a logical AND of two - one searching for each word.