# Regex to match string containing two names in any order

Tags: regex, string

I need logical AND in regex.

something like

jack AND james

agree with following strings

- 'hi **jack** here is **james**'
- 'hi **james** here is **jack**'

Comment: Possible duplicate: [mulitple-words-in-any-order-using-regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177081/mulitple-words-in-any-order-using-regex)

Comment: @AndersonGreen, the question was prematurely locked. The answers are severely lacking as those solutions are not viable since most regex don't recognize **lookaround** and **mode quantifier**. I believe **quantifier** existed at the point of the question being asked.

Answer (score 393, accepted):

You can do checks using **positive lookaheads**. Here is a summary from the indispensable [regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

> Lookahead and lookbehind, collectively called “lookaround”, are
> zero-length assertions...lookaround actually matches characters, but
> then gives up the match, returning only the result: match or no match.
> That is why they are called “assertions”. They do not consume
> characters in the string, but only assert whether a match is possible
> or not.

It then goes on to explain that positive lookaheads are used to *assert* that what follows matches a certain expression without *taking up* characters in that matching expression.

So here is an expression using two subsequent postive lookaheads to assert that the phrase matches `jack` and `james` in either order:

```
^(?=.*\bjack\b)(?=.*\bjames\b).*$
```

[Test it.](http://www.rubular.com/r/iglM0YiFSE)

The expressions in parentheses starting with `?=` are the positive lookaheads. I'll break down the pattern:

1. `^` asserts the start of the expression to be matched.
2. `(?=.*\bjack\b)` is the first positive lookahead saying that what follows must match `.*\bjack\b`.
3. `.*` means any character zero or more times.
4. `\b` means any word boundary (white space, start of expression, end of expression, etc.).
5. `jack` is literally those four characters in a row (the same for `james` in the next positive lookahead).
6. `$` asserts the end of the expression to me matched.

So the first lookahead says "what follows (and is not itself a lookahead or lookbehind) must be an expression that starts with zero or more of any characters followed by a word boundary and then `jack` and another word boundary," and the second look ahead says "what follows must be an expression that starts with zero or more of any characters followed by a word boundary and then `james` and another word boundary." After the two lookaheads is `.*` which simply matches any characters zero or more times and `$` which matches the end of the expression.

"start with anything then jack or james then end with anything" satisfies the first lookahead because there are a number of characters then the word `jack`, and it satisfies the second lookahead because there are a number of characters (which just so happens to include `jack`, but that is not necessary to satisfy the second lookahead) then the word `james`. Neither lookahead asserts the end of the expression, so the `.*` that follows can go beyond what satisfies the lookaheads, such as "then end with anything".

I think you get the idea, but just to be absolutely clear, here is with `jack` and `james` reversed, i.e. "start with anything then james or jack then end with anything"; it satisfies the first lookahead because there are a number of characters then the word `james`, and it satisfies the second lookahead because there are a number of characters (which just so happens to include `james`, but that is not necessary to satisfy the second lookahead) then the word `jack`. As before, neither lookahead asserts the end of the expression, so the `.*` that follows can go beyond what satisfies the lookaheads, such as "then end with anything".

This approach has the advantage that you can easily specify multiple conditions.

```
^(?=.*\bjack\b)(?=.*\bjames\b)(?=.*\bjason\b)(?=.*\bjules\b).*$
```

Comment: `vim` syntax: `^\(.*\<jack\>\)\@=\(.*\<james\>\@=\).*$` or `\v^(.*<jack>)@=(.*<james>)@=.*$`

Comment: Does anyone know why this would break (in JavaScript at least) when I try to search for strings starting with '#'? `^(?=.*\b#friday\b)(?=.*\b#tgif\b).*$` fails to match `blah #tgif blah #friday blah` but `^(?=.*\bfriday\b)(?=.*\btgif\b).*$` works fine.

Comment: This isn't working for me, as demoed here: https://regex101.com/r/xI9qT0/1

Comment: @TonyH, for JavaScript you can remove the last `$` symbol from the pattern or remove the new line character from the test string, other languages (Python, PHP) on this website work perfectly. Also you can remove `.*$` from the end — regexp still will be matches the test string, but it's without selecting of the whole test string as match.

Comment: Adding `(?i)` can also make it case insensitive.
`^(?i)(?=.*\bjack\b)(?=.*\bjames\b).*$`

Comment: Depending on the use case (printing the line containing the match, or perhaps just knowing if there is a match), this simpler one may suffice: `^(?=[\s\S]*jack)(?=[\s\S]*james)`

Comment: Nice. But I guess that's not supported in neither implementation of AWK.

Answer (score 175):

Try:

```
james.*jack
```

If you want both at the same time, then `or` them:

```
james.*jack|jack.*james
```

Comment: The accepted answer worked. this also worked perfectly for me. For searching code in visual studio 'find results'.

Comment: This one works for me and is much more concise & easy to understand than the accepted answer!

Comment: I needed a solution that only had two names to match, so this answer is more concise for that case. But the accepted answer becomes more concise beyond 2 since the number of "or"s increases factorially. For 3 names there would be 6 "or"s, 4 names would be 24 "or"s, etc.

Comment: I would recommend to make it lazy `james.*?jack|jack.*?james`. This will help on large texts.

Comment: Note this will also match such names as "jacky" and "jameson"

Comment: Only issue is you can't use proper capture grouping with this method without needing n² groups.

Comment: @GershomMaes you're right but not `jameson` here is the [demo](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/de48d56e1a61).

Comment: @AmineKOUIS in the demo, try "hi jameson here is jack" - you'll see `jameson` is matched. This regex solves the issue: `\bjames\b.*\bjack\b|\bjack\b.*\bjames\b`

Answer (score 60):

**Explanation of command that i am going to write**:-

`.` means any character, digit can come in place of .

`*` means zero or more occurrences of thing written just previous to it.

`|` means *'or'*.

So,

```
james.*jack
```

would search `james`  , then any number of character until `jack` comes.

Since **you want either `jack.*james` or `james.*jack`**

Hence ***Command***:

```
jack.*james|james.*jack
```

Comment: As a side note - you could also have edited @icyrock's answer (which is the same as yours, just 6 years earlier), your explanation is very useful on its own.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, i however feel the need to point out that in VSCode search, your answer  **jack.*james | james.*jack** will take the spaces between the '|' (or) symbol into consideration during the search. **jack.*james|james.*jack** works and doesnt look for the spaces

Comment: Don't you need 2000 rep for the edit privilege?

Comment: the second one matche also "jacky" and "jameson" check this [demo](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/de48d56e1a61).

Answer (score 37):

Its short and sweet

```
(?=.*jack)(?=.*james)
```

---

### Test Cases:

```js
[
  "xxx james xxx jack xxx",
  "jack xxx james ",
  "jack xxx jam ",
  "  jam and jack",
  "jack",
  "james",
]
.forEach(s => console.log(/(?=.*james)(?=.*jack)/.test(s)) )
```

Comment: could you say how it works? lookahead needs word before, and there is nothing. in this case `element (?=.*jack)` result will be `element`, for `(?=.*jack)` there will be no result . Olso tried on example string here: https://regex101.com

Answer (score 9):

You can do:

```
\bjack\b.*\bjames\b|\bjames\b.*\bjack\b
```

Answer (score 7):

[The expression in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4389683/6553328) does that for one `jack` and one `james` in **any order**.

Here, we'd explore other scenarios.

### METHOD 1: One `jack` and One `james`

Just in case, two `jack` or two `james` would not be allowed, only one `jack` and one `james` would be valid, we can likely design an expression similar to:

```
^(?!.*\bjack\b.*\bjack\b)(?!.*\bjames\b.*\bjames\b)(?=.*\bjames\b)(?=.*\bjack\b).*$
```

Here, we would exclude those instances using these statements:

```
(?!.*\bjack\b.*\bjack\b)
```

and,

```
(?!.*\bjames\b.*\bjames\b)
```

#### [RegEx Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/ve1RAo/1/)

We can also simplify that to:

```
^(?!.*\bjack\b.*\bjack\b|.*\bjames\b.*\bjames\b)(?=.*\bjames\b|.*\bjack\b).*$
```

#### [RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/n3stoK/1/)

---

If you wish to simplify/update/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/ve1RAo/1/). You can watch the matching steps or modify them in [this debugger link](https://regex101.com/r/ve1RAo/1/debugger), if you'd be interested. The debugger demonstrates that how [a RegEx engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines) might step by step consume some sample input strings and would perform the matching process.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

#### Test

```js
const regex = /^(?!.*\bjack\b.*\bjack\b|.*\bjames\b.*\bjames\b)(?=.*\bjames\b|.*\bjack\b).*$/gm;
const str = `hi jack here is james
hi james here is jack
hi james jack here is jack james
hi jack james here is james jack
hi jack jack here is jack james
hi james james here is james jack
hi jack jack jack here is james
`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

---

### METHOD 2: One `jack` and One `james` in a specific order

The expression can be also designed for first a `james` then a `jack`, similar to the following one:

```
^(?!.*\bjack\b.*\bjack\b|.*\bjames\b.*\bjames\b)(?=.*\bjames\b.*\bjack\b).*$
```

#### [RegEx Demo 3](https://regex101.com/r/wdZ75t/1/)

and vice versa:

```
^(?!.*\bjack\b.*\bjack\b|.*\bjames\b.*\bjames\b)(?=.*\bjack\b.*\bjames\b).*$
```

#### [RegEx Demo 4](https://regex101.com/r/EagzjY/1/)

Comment: Great explanation. It would be even better if your method 1 could match both 'james' AND 'jack' in any order. Testing it, I found that your regex expression matches single 'james' or 'jack'

Answer (score 7):

No need for two [lookaheads](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), one substring can be normally *matched*.

```
^(?=.*?\bjack\b).*?\bjames\b.*
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/3KRcUn/1)

Lookarounds are zero-length assertions (conditions). The lookahead here checks at `^` [*start*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) if `jack` occurs later in the string and on success *matches* up to `james` and [`.*`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441015/symbol-for-any-number-of-any-characters-in-regex) the rest (could be removed). [Lazy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2301291/5527985) [dot](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) is used before words (enclosed in `\b` [word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)). Use the [`i`-flag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9655186/5527985) for *ignoring case*.

Comment: Very Good answer, thanks for sharing. One question: do we need `.*` after last `\b` or will that work without it also?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Thank you for your comment, good point! For just validating the `.*` in the end is indeed useless, it's just needed if the full match is wanted.

Answer (score 5):

Vim has a branch operator `\&` that is useful when searching for a line containing a set of words, in any order. Moreover, extending the set of required words is trivial.

For example,

`/.*jack\&.*james`

will match a line containing `jack` and `james`, in any order.

Likewise,

`/\<\(\w*jack\&\w*james\)`

will match a variable name containing `jack` and `james`, in any order.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18309859/what-is-the-pattern-in-vims-regex/58694336#58694336) for more information on usage.  I am not aware of any other regex flavor that implements branching; the operator is not even documented on the [Regular Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) wikipedia entry.

Answer (score 5):

You can make use of regex's **quantifier** feature since `lookaround` may not be supported all the time.

```
(\bjames\b){1,}.*(\bjack\b){1,}|(\bjack\b){1,}.*(\bjames\b){1,}
```

Comment: Why no one tries this, 0 voted answers might be the best, thanks mate.

Comment: @captain_majid, I apologize. After intense research and based on false positives data, I realized my original answer was wrong. I've fixed the regex code. This correct regex will work perfectly as expected.

Comment: Your 1st example worked fine with me, and strangely even a simpler one like that worked also:
`\b(word1|word2|word3|word4|etc)\b`

I've tested it here: https://rubular.com/r/Pgn2d6dXXXHoh7

Answer (score 0):

All of the answers so far work for *finding* a match, but they don't all work for *highlighting* that match.  For example: if you want to use grep's "--only-matching" or "--color" options, then there's only one kind of answer (so far) that will work: `james.*jack|jack.*james`.  I'll call this the **permutations technique**, and the other ones the **lookaround technique** and the **vim branch technique**.

The **lookaround technique** won't do any highlighting at all, because it will always match a zero-length string, because - by definition - that's what lookarounds do.  That is, for this input text:

```
hi jack here is james
hi james here is jack
```

a (perl) regex of `(?=.*jack)(?=.*james)` won't highlight anything.  You can test this by running this command in most any unix shell:

```
printf 'hi jack here is james\nhi james here is jack\n' | grep --color --perl '(?=.*jack)(?=.*james)'
```

Some of the answers here add `.*` to the beginning and the end.  That will highlight something - the whole line - but that doesn't help if our goal is to highlight the words we're looking for, and what's in between those words, and nothing more.

The **vim branch technique** (AKA `\&`) will highlight something that might look useful at a glance, but it's probably not what you want.  For the same input text,
a vim search for `/.*james\&.*jack` will highlight `hi jack` and `hi james here is jack`.
To test this from the shell, run this:

```
printf 'hi jack here is james\nhi james here is jack\n' | vim -R - '+/.*james\&.*jack'
```

Only the **permutations technique** will highlight the most useful things: `jack here is james` and `james here is jack`.  To test this from the shell:

```
printf 'hi jack here is james\nhi james here is jack\n' | grep --color --perl 'james.*jack|jack.*james'
```

All of what I've written here assumes that you want a technique that will generalize to three or more words.