# Symbol for any number of any characters in regex?

Tags: regex

I'm wondering is there a symbol for any number (including zero) of any characters

Answer (score 328, accepted):

```
.*
```

`.` is any char, `*` means repeated zero or more times.

Comment: Good answer, would just add see here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: A sneaky gotcha is that `.*` does *not* match new-line character (`'\n'`). See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651725/match-multiline-text-using-regular-expression) for more info on that topic.

Answer (score 52):

You can use this regular expression (any whitespace or any non-whitespace) as many times as possible down to and including 0.

```
[\s\S]*
```

This expression will match as few as possible, but as many as necessary for the rest of the expression.

```
[\s\S]*?
```

For example, in this regex `[\s\S]*?B` will match `aB` in `aBaaaaB`.  But in this regex `[\s\S]*B` will match `aBaaaaB` in `aBaaaaB`.

Comment: is there any difference between [\s\S] and .?

Comment: @linqu, `.` will sometimes not match `\n` (newline), depending on the multiline option, but `[\s\S]` will match any character.

Answer (score 29):

Do you mean

```
.*
```

`.` any character, except newline character, with dotall mode it includes also the newline characters

`*` any amount of the preceding expression, including 0 times

Answer (score 6):

I would use `.*`. `.` matches any character, `*` signifies 0 or more occurrences. You might need a DOTALL switch to the regex to capture new lines with `.`.

Answer (score -9):

Yes, there is one, it's the asterisk: `*`

```
a* // looks for 0 or more instances of "a"
```

This should be covered in any Java regex tutorial or documentation that you look up.