# regex match if string contain all the words or a condition

Tags: regex

im making a simple word game with php and regex, how can we search that if a string have to require two or more words?

lets say

```
"cat"
"dog"
"play" x 2
```

if

"cat dog play play" **pass**

"hello a cat dog playing a play" **not pass**, only 1 "play"

"cat" **not pass**, no dog and 2x play

"i want a cat and a dog play with me and play with grandfather" **pass**

how can we match it with regex?

Comment: Why don't you solve it with 3 regexes instead of one? It would be much easier. I doubt it's possible with one.

Comment: yeah i can do something like `if(preg_match("dog") && preg_match("etc") && ... )` but will it affect the performance? if i match alot of things?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10832519/regex-match-at-least-two-search-terms

Comment: @JohnB Of course it’s *possible*. It just isn’t very nice to look at.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The regex you're looking for is:

```
/(?=.*?\bcat\b)(?=.*?\bdog\b)(?=(.*?\bplay\b){2})^.*$/
```

**Explanation:** I believe words `cat`, `dog` and `play` (twice) can appear in the text in any order but they must all be present in the sentence to qualify. Above regex is using positive lookahead to make sure the presence of above conditions.

[Here is the online working demo of above RegEx](http://www.rubular.com/r/itRFAYpQVq)

Answer (score 2):

Try `preg_match_all(/cat.+dog(.+play){2}/i,$str,$out);`

Comment: That's quite restricted, the words need to be wirtten in the right order.

Comment: how about if not in the right order? anyway it doesnt work even if its in the same order. maybe because /i? wait let me search what is `/i`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the last example. I updated the answer. And /i means case-insensitive