# Regex: match at least N number of search terms but with patterns dependent on position

Tags: regex

My question is similar to that in [regex: Match at least two search terms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10832519/regex-match-at-least-two-search-terms), but with added complexity:

Given a set of M numerical strings of same length:

```
11001100
11101010
10010010
00101101
```

And given substring patterns of the type "11 at position 0" or "10 at position 6" (with the position being any multiple of 2), how can I search for strings matching at least N of these patterns?

For example: `^(11|\d{2}10|\d{6}10)` matches all strings. However if I add {3,} to the regex to match "11101010" only (because it satisfies three out of three of those OR cases), it fails. Does anyone know how I can structure a regex like this?

If it matters, the patterns can also cover the same substring position, so for example it could be (11|\d{6}10|\d{6}00), and this ideally would match both the first and second lines in my example if I wanted to only catch strings with two or more matches.

Comment: This `^(11|\d{2}10|\d{6}10)` has a match in all 4 strings.

Comment: Oops, sorry, fixed.

Comment: it might be easier to check if each line starts at 11 or ends at 10 than writing a regular expression

Comment: I guess my question wasn't clear enough, the position can be anywhere in the string. I'll edit it.

Comment: I think the question is not really clear. In the same string, `^11` can match only once. Matching 10 at position 6 can only be matched once, as there is only 1 position 6, and when matched the regex engine will go forward. You can use a quantifier `{3}` for example if there are enough characters in the string to match it like `^(11|\d{2}10|\d{6}10){3}`  for string `11101000000010`

Answer (score 0):

Is [this](https://regex101.com/r/EYmGXq/1) the expected result?

```
(\b(11\d{6}|10\d{6}|\d{6}01)\n?){3,}
```