# Html Agility Pack get all elements by class

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I am taking a stab at html agility pack and having trouble finding the right way to go about this.

For example:

```
var findclasses = _doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div").Where(d => d.Attributes.Contains("class"));
```

However, obviously you can add classes to a lot more then divs so I tried this..

```
var allLinksWithDivAndClass = _doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@class=\"float\"]");
```

But that doesn't handle the cases where you add multiple classes and "float" is just one of them like this..

```
class="className float anotherclassName"
```

Is there a way to handle all of this?  I basically want to select all nodes that have a class = and contains float.

**Answer has been documented on my blog with a full explanation at: [Html Agility Pack Get All Elements by Class](http://www.adamthings.com/post/2013/10/14/html-agility-pack-get-elements-class/)

Answer (score 97, accepted):

(Updated 2018-03-17)

## The problem:

The problem, as you've spotted, is that `String.Contains` does not perform a word-boundary check, so `Contains("float")` will return `true` for both "foo float bar" (correct) and "unfloating" (which is incorrect).

The solution is to ensure that "float" (or whatever your desired class-name is) appears *alongside a word-boundary* at both ends. A word-boundary is either the start (or end) of a string (or line), whitespace, certain punctuation, etc. In most regular-expressions this is `\b`. So the regex you want is simply: `\bfloat\b`.

A downside to using a `Regex` instance is that they can be slow to run if you don't use the `.Compiled` option - and they can be slow to compile. So you should cache the regex instance. This is more difficult if the class-name you're looking for changes at runtime.

Alternatively you can search a string for words by word-boundaries without using a regex by implementing the regex as a C# string-processing function, being careful not to cause any new string or other object allocation (e.g. not using `String.Split`).

### Approach 1: Using a regular-expression:

Suppose you just want to look for elements with a single, design-time specified class-name:

```
class Program {

    private static readonly Regex _classNameRegex = new Regex( @"\bfloat\b", RegexOptions.Compiled );

    private static IEnumerable<HtmlNode> GetFloatElements(HtmlDocument doc) {
        return doc
            .Descendants()
            .Where( n => n.NodeType == NodeType.Element )
            .Where( e => e.Name == "div" && _classNameRegex.IsMatch( e.GetAttributeValue("class", "") ) );
    }
}
```

If you need to choose a single class-name at runtime then you can build a regex:

```
private static IEnumerable<HtmlNode> GetElementsWithClass(HtmlDocument doc, String className) {

    Regex regex = new Regex( "\\b" + Regex.Escape( className ) + "\\b", RegexOptions.Compiled );

    return doc
        .Descendants()
        .Where( n => n.NodeType == NodeType.Element )
        .Where( e => e.Name == "div" && regex.IsMatch( e.GetAttributeValue("class", "") ) );
}
```

If you have multiple class-names and you want to match all of them, you could create an array of `Regex` objects and ensure they're all matching, or combine them into a single `Regex` using lookarounds, but this results [in horrendously complicated expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389644/regex-to-match-string-containing-two-names-in-any-order) - so using a `Regex[]` is probably better:

```
using System.Linq;

private static IEnumerable<HtmlNode> GetElementsWithClass(HtmlDocument doc, String[] classNames) {

    Regex[] exprs = new Regex[ classNames.Length ];
    for( Int32 i = 0; i < exprs.Length; i++ ) {
        exprs[i] = new Regex( "\\b" + Regex.Escape( classNames[i] ) + "\\b", RegexOptions.Compiled );
    }

    return doc
        .Descendants()
        .Where( n => n.NodeType == NodeType.Element )
        .Where( e =>
            e.Name == "div" &&
            exprs.All( r =>
                r.IsMatch( e.GetAttributeValue("class", "") )
            )
        );
}
```

#### Approach 2: Using non-regex string matching:

The advantage of using a custom C# method to do string matching instead of a regex is hypothetically faster performance and reduced memory usage (though `Regex` may be faster in some circumstances - always profile your code first, kids!)

This method below: `CheapClassListContains` provides a fast word-boundary-checking string matching function that can be used the same way as `regex.IsMatch`:

```
private static IEnumerable<HtmlNode> GetElementsWithClass(HtmlDocument doc, String className) {

    return doc
        .Descendants()
        .Where( n => n.NodeType == NodeType.Element )
        .Where( e =>
            e.Name == "div" &&
            CheapClassListContains(
                e.GetAttributeValue("class", ""),
                className,
                StringComparison.Ordinal
            )
        );
}

/// <summary>Performs optionally-whitespace-padded string search without new string allocations.</summary>
/// <remarks>A regex might also work, but constructing a new regex every time this method is called would be expensive.</remarks>
private static Boolean CheapClassListContains(String haystack, String needle, StringComparison comparison)
{
    if( String.Equals( haystack, needle, comparison ) ) return true;
    Int32 idx = 0;
    while( idx + needle.Length <= haystack.Length )
    {
        idx = haystack.IndexOf( needle, idx, comparison );
        if( idx == -1 ) return false;

        Int32 end = idx + needle.Length;

        // Needle must be enclosed in whitespace or be at the start/end of string
        Boolean validStart = idx == 0               || Char.IsWhiteSpace( haystack[idx - 1] );
        Boolean validEnd   = end == haystack.Length || Char.IsWhiteSpace( haystack[end] );
        if( validStart && validEnd ) return true;

        idx++;
    }
    return false;
}
```

#### Approach 3: Using a CSS Selector library:

HtmlAgilityPack is somewhat stagnated doesn't support `.querySelector` and `.querySelectorAll`, but there are third-party libraries that extend HtmlAgilityPack with it: namely [Fizzler](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Fizzler.Systems.HtmlAgilityPack/) and [CssSelectors](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack.CssSelectors/). Both Fizzler and CssSelectors implement `QuerySelectorAll`, so you can use it like so:

```
private static IEnumerable<HtmlNode> GetDivElementsWithFloatClass(HtmlDocument doc) {

    return doc.QuerySelectorAll( "div.float" );
}
```

With runtime-defined classes:

```
private static IEnumerable<HtmlNode> GetDivElementsWithClasses(HtmlDocument doc, IEnumerable<String> classNames) {

    String selector = "div." + String.Join( ".", classNames );

    return doc.QuerySelectorAll( selector  );
}
```

Comment: Wont this cause only Divs to be found?  What if I add that class to a <span class="someClass float someClass2".

Comment: Then remove the "div" predicate.

Comment: can you just do .Descendants("") ?

Comment: `Contains()` doesnt exist on the attribute so replace `d.Attributes["class"].Contains("float")` with `d.Attributes["class"].Value.Split(' ').Any(b => b.Equals("float"))`

Comment: Oh, `Contains` works for me because I wrote my own extension method.

Comment: If there were a class named `floating` then `Value.Contains("float")` would also match that

Comment: Web scraping spree :-)

Comment: I spent hours trying to get `HtmlAgilityPack` to work and this was the only example that I actually got to work for attributes.  I'm not sure if things changed with different versions, but my install does not have `SelectNodes` and `HtmlNavigator`.

Comment: @Dai re: the RegEx comment in CheapClassListContains().  Why not just create the RegEx as a class level static element?  Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @RobertOschler `CheapClassListContains` is potentially cheaper than a regex and implements the same logic - but yes, that is also an option.

Answer (score 93):

You can solve your issue by using the 'contains' function within your Xpath query, as below:

```
var allElementsWithClassFloat = 
   _doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[contains(@class,'float')]")
```

To reuse this in a function do something similar to the following:

```
string classToFind = "float";    
var allElementsWithClassFloat = 
   _doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(string.Format("//*[contains(@class,'{0}')]", classToFind));
```

Comment: what would be the object type `allElementsWithClassFloat`?

Comment: `allElementsWithClassFloat` is an HtmlNodeCollection

Comment: Instead of string.Format you can also use `$"//*[contains(@class,'{classToFind}')]"`

Comment: what will happen if you have a class with name float-xs?

Comment: @SameeraKumarasingha the classes 'float-xs' and 'unfloating' will both be included in the `allElementsWithClassFloat` list. Please take a look at @Dai's answer instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13774240/3678079

Comment: As of version v1.6.5 of Html Agility Pack, it contains .HasClass("class-name") extension methoda.

`IEnumerable<HtmlNode> nodes =
    htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants(0)
        .Where(n => n.HasClass("class-name"));`

Answer (score 6):

I used this extension method a lot in my project. Hope it will help one of you guys.

```
public static bool HasClass(this HtmlNode node, params string[] classValueArray)
    {
        var classValue = node.GetAttributeValue("class", "");
        var classValues = classValue.Split(' ');
        return classValueArray.All(c => classValues.Contains(c));
    }
```

Comment: Don't use `ToLower()` when what you really want is to IgnoreCase comparison. Passing `StringComparison.CultureIgnoreCase` is cleaner and shows a more explicit intent.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static List<HtmlNode> GetTagsWithClass(string html,List<string> @class)
    {
        // LoadHtml(html);           
        var result = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants()
            .Where(x =>x.Attributes.Contains("class") && @class.Contains(x.Attributes["class"].Value)).ToList();          
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you looking for class in some tag (like  or any other).
Try this one

```
 var spans = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span"); //or other tag or all nodes

 var span_with_class = spans.Where(_ => _.Attributes["class"].Value.Split(' ').Any(b => b.Equals("someClass")));
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Answers have more long-term value if they come with explanations about how/why the code solves the problem.

Answer (score -6):

You can use the following script:

```
var findclasses = _doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div").Where(d => 
    d.Attributes.Contains("class") && d.Attributes["class"].Value.Contains("float")
);
```