# Pulling a specific link from a site

Tags: c#, html, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I a m trying to pull links from a website, the HTML of what I want look like the below:

```
<div class="default-2-3">
<h4>
  <a href="/en/news/esports/esports-editorial/na-lcs-week-8-tease-tsm">NA LCS Week 8 Tease: TSM</a>
 </h4>
```

My test code looks like:

```
string mainURL = "http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/";
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(mainURL);

var findClass = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
                   .Where(d => d.Attributes.Contains("class") && 
                               d.Attributes["class"].Value.Contains("default-2-3"));
MessageBox.Show(findClass.ElementAt(1).ToString());
```

Currently the message box shows:

> HtmlAgilityPack.htmlNode

I based my code off of this [finding specific link from website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13771083/html-agility-pack-get-all-elements-by-class), I am new to using HTMLAgilityPack beyond just copying the XPath.

For reference, the site I am trying to extract information is: http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/

Comment: Can you share the link so it would be easier to test?

Comment: I added tht link. M adeel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close to the final step. Just a little more.

```
var findClass = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div").Where(d => d.Attributes.Contains("class") && d.Attributes["class"].Value.Contains("default-2-3")).Select(_ => _.Descendants("a").FirstOrDefault()?.Attributes["href"]);
```

Comment: Hello hung Cao, I used the code however when i do     MessageBox.Show(findClass.ElementAt(1).ToString()); I still get htmlagilitypack in message box.

Comment: It's an array of HtmlAttribute. If you want to get the first item then `findClass.ElementAt(1).Value`

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are more than one div with the same `class=default-2-3`
You are trying to fetch the very first which you can get by doing this:

```
var href = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(".//div[@class='default-2-3']//h4//a[@href]").Select(x=>x.Attributes["href"].Value);
```

Comment: Hello M Adeel, I do want to pull more than 1 of the links.