# How to extract data from specific html class agility pack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I want to extract not the whole web-page but only text from one class, I haven't found how to do this for my code. I want text from td class="result-neutral"
this is html code:

```
<td class="result-neutral" xseid="xz1nBfht"><a href="/hockey/russia/khl/ska-st-petersburg-metallurg-magnitogorsk-xz1nBfht/">3 - 2 </a></td>
```

Now I have sych a C# code(Info is the name of a textbox):

```
 HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
        doc = hw.Load("http://www.sportstats.com/hockey/russia/detail/ska-st-petersburg-zVJwe4ER/");
       var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("td");
 string result = "";
        foreach (var item in nodes)
        {
            result += item.InnerText+Environment.NewLine;
        }
        Info.Text = result;

    }
```

To be honest, I'd better get the score, which in the example above is ***3-2***

Comment: You may try the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13771083/html-agility-pack-get-all-elements-by-class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that site is using AJAX to load the scores so it will not be available for HTMLAgilityPack when you use their `.Load()`.

Perhaps you can use WebBrowser object in C# to load the page first and then use HAP to load the content. There are ton of examples about this.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! You're absolutely right, this code works for other web-pages