# why does HtmlAgilityPack Reverse Output

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

i need to remove the tag if the class value is `"Section2 RenderAsSection2"`

This is the input

```
    <body>
<div id="Sec3" class="Section2 RenderAsSection2">
<h3 class="Heading"><span class="HeadingNumber">1.1.2 </span>Text1</h3>
<div class="Para ParaOneEmphasisChild">Text 2 <span class="EmphasisTypeItalic">decay</span>. Text3</div><div class="Para">Text4 <span class="EmphasisTypeItalic">decay</span> processes.</div>
</div>
</body>
```

and this should be the output

```
<body>

<h3 class="Heading"><span class="HeadingNumber">1.1.2 </span>Text1</h3>
<div class="Para ParaOneEmphasisChild">Text 2 <span class="EmphasisTypeItalic">decay</span>. Text3</div><div class="Para">Text4 <span class="EmphasisTypeItalic">decay</span> processes.</div>

</body>
```

this is my code

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            doc.Load(@"1.html");

            var en = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div");
            var ll = en.ToList();

            foreach (var item in ll)
            {
                foreach (var att in item.Attributes)
                {
                    if (att.Value == "Section2 RenderAsSection2")
                    {

                            item.ParentNode.RemoveChild(item, true);


                    }


                }

            }
```

But the output is

```
<body>

<div class="Para">Text4 <span class="EmphasisTypeItalic">decay</span> processes.</div><div class="Para ParaOneEmphasisChild">Text 2 <span class="EmphasisTypeItalic">decay</span>. Text3</div>
<h3 class="Heading"><span class="HeadingNumber">1.1.2 </span>Text1</h3>

</body>
```

How does it became that way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13774240/6741868), you can simplify your code as follows:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"1.html");

var en = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants( "div" ).Where( d => d.Attributes.Contains("class") && d.Attributes["class"].Value  == "Section2 RenderAsSection2");
```

**EDITED**:

```
foreach (var item in en)
{
    foreach (HtmlNode child in item.ChildNodes)
    {
        item.ParentNode.InsertBefore(child, item);
    }
    item.Remove();
}
```

Comment: But the output is still the same

Comment: Check out my edited code, it preserves the order. I tested it with your html code as well :)