# Regex to match strings in any order, and also to limit to just those strings

Tags: regex

[Regex to match string containing two names in any order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389644/regex-to-match-string-containing-two-names-in-any-order) has a good explanation of how to match strings in any order. So using

```
(?=.*\bjack\b)(?=.*\bjames\b)
```

Will match

```
jack,james
```

and

```
james,jack
```

However, it will also match

```
jack,james,jill
```

How can I construct a regex to match string in any order, but only match those string (i.e. a regex that will match jack and james in any order, but not match a string that contains anything other than jack and james)

Comment: should `james,jack,james,james` be accepted?

Comment: It would be nice to have the option to accept either `jack,james` or `jack,james,jack,james`, but for my purposes matching `jack,james,jack,james` is fine.

Comment: **Contradiction:** `but not match a string that contains anything other than jack and james` How about spaces and commas there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what exactly you mean by "anything other than jack and james", but the general idea would be to match some number of `\b(jack|james)\b`, surrounded by other characters:

```
^\W*(\b(jack|james)\b\W*)*$
```

You can specify the exact number, or range, of matches instead of using `*`. For example, to match exactly 2 or 3 such words:

```
^\W*(\b(jack|james)\b\W*){2,3}$
```