# Check if string matches multiple substrings/regexes

Tags: ruby, regex

I have an array of paragraphs and an array of keywords. I want to iterate over the paragraphs array and return `true` for elements that include all of my keywords. The keywords can be in any order, but all of them must be found in the same paragraph in order for it to be `true`, not just some of them.

Is there a way I can do this using one `Regexp.union` or one regex, without `=~ regex1 && =~ regex2 && =~ regex3 && =~ regex4` etc?

Comment: is your keywords array just words or patterns too?

Comment: Just words. But I can easily turn it into an array of one-word patterns like `/cromulent/`.

Comment: This could help: [Regex to match string containing two names in any order](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4389644/477037)

Answer (score 0):

If the pattern array contains only keywords and no patters:

```
str = "foo went to bar with abc and xyz"

pats = ["abc","xyz","foo","bar"]
pats.all? { |e| str.include?(e) }
# => true

pats = ["abc","xyz","foo","bar", "no"]
pats.all? { |e| str.include?(e) }
# => false
```

If the pattern array contain patterns:

```
pats = [/abc/, /xyz$/, /^foo/, /bar/]
pats.all? { |e| str =~ e }
# => true

pats = [/abc/, /xyz$/, /^foo/, /bar/, /no/]
pats.all? { |e| str =~ e }
# => false
```

Comment: Anchored regexes are unnecessary in the example, I think. No one looks for keywords this way. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev that's true. I just wanted to give an example for regex patterns match too. So I lazily used same keywords as patterns :P

Comment: I mean, _anchored_ regexes (`/^foo/`) :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following:

```
str = "I have an array of paragraphs and an array of keywords. I want to iterate over the paragraphs array and return true for elements that include all of my keywords. The keywords can be in any order, but all of them must be found in the same paragraph in order for it to be true, not just some of them."
```

Edit: I initially misunderstood the question. You can just do the following for each paragraph:

```
words = %w(have iterate true) 
(words - str.scan(/\w+/)).empty?
  #=> true

words = %w(have iterate cat)
(words - str.scan(/\w+/)).empty?
  #=> false
```

When I initially read the question I thought the words in the array must appear in each paragraph *in the same order*. For the record, my solution with that additional requirement follows.

```
words = %w(have iterate true)   
r = /\b#{words.join('\b.*?\b')}\b/
   #=> /\bhave\b.*?\biterate\b.*?\btrue\b/
str =~ r #=> 2 (a match)

words = %w(true have iterate)
r = /\b#{words.join('\b.*?\b')}\b/
str =~ r #=> nil

words = %w(have iterate true false)   
r = /\b#{words.join('\b.*?\b')}\b/
str =~ r #=> nil
```

Comment: This enforces order of keywords. We don't usually care about the order.

Comment: @Sergio, ha! I incorrectly interpreted,  "...found in the same paragraph in order for it to be true". It's clear from the rest of the question that order is not required.

Answer (score -1):

I have never used Ruby but I can give you the logic to use here. Hope it helps

```
array_words
array_paragraphs
number_words = array_words
count =0

foreach para (array_paragraph)
{
    foreach word (array_word)
    {
        if (para =~ m/word/gi)
        {
            count++
        }
    }
    if (count == number_words)
    {
        print all words present in the paragraph
    }
    count = 0
}
```

Comment: Ruby can do much much better than _this_.