# JavaScript regex to match multiple optional strings, in any order

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I've been wrestling with this for a while and can't figure it out. I see in [Regex to match string containing two names in any order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389644/regex-to-match-string-containing-two-names-in-any-order) that lookarounds can be used to look for words occurring in any order. I added some additional groups to the example from that post:

```js
const regex = /^(?=.*\b(jack)\b)(?=.*\b(james)\b).*$/;
"hi james this is jack".match(regex);
  // => ["hi james this is jack", "jack", "james"]
```

However, I also want to make both of the words optional. That is, something like this:

```js
"hi james this is jack".match(someMagicRegex);
  // => ["hi james this is jack", "jack", "james"]

"hi this is jack".match(someMagicRegex);
  // => ["hi this is jack", "jack", undefined]

"hi james".match(someMagicRegex);
  // => ["hi james", undefined, "james"]
```

The important thing would be that the matches remain in the correct order. That is the `jack` match would always be the second element in the matches array.

I've tried adding `?` at different places (including after new groupings), but nothing I tried produced the desired result.

Is something like this possible?

**UPDATE**: To be more specific, I'm going to be using this on a series of CSS media queries and am looking to match optional `min-width: Xpx` and `max-width: Ypx` expressions:

```js
"only screen and (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 599px)".match(someMagicRegex);
  // => ["...", "500", "599"]

"only screen and (min-width: 500px)".match(someMagicRegex);
  // => ["...", "500", undefined]

"(max-width: 599px)".match(someMagicRegex);
  // => ["...", undefined, "599"]
```

(Where the second match would be the numeric portion of the min-width value and the third match would be the numeric portion of the max-width value.)

Comment: Regular expression is probably not the best option for this.

Comment: How many names do you need to match against?

Comment: I've added an update showing how I am hoping to use regex matching. Unless there's a better way to accomplish the whole thing. Starting to hit tunnel vision :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure do you need full match as first result in matches array (?), but this could give you an idea. No 'magic regex' (from me, at least), just plain regex `array`, with capturing groups:

```js
regex = ["min-width:\\s*(\\d+)px","max-width:\\s*(\\d+)px"];

str = "only screen and (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 599px)";

//str = "only screen and (min-width: 500px)"; 

//str="(max-width: 599px)";


matches = [];

for( i = 0; i < regex.length; i++ ) {
    if( RegExp(regex[i]).exec(str) ) {
        matches.push(RegExp(regex[i]).exec(str)[1]);
    } else {
        matches.push(undefined)
    }
}

console.log(matches);
```

Test case 2:

```js
regex = ["min-width:\\s*(\\d+)px","max-width:\\s*(\\d+)px"];



str = "only screen and (min-width: 500px)"; 

//str="(max-width: 599px)";


matches = [];

for( i = 0; i < regex.length; i++ ) {
    if( RegExp(regex[i]).exec(str) ) {
        matches.push(RegExp(regex[i]).exec(str)[1]);
    } else {
        matches.push(undefined)
    }
}

console.log(matches);
```

Test case 3:

```js
regex = ["min-width:\\s*(\\d+)px","max-width:\\s*(\\d+)px"];



str="(max-width: 599px)";


matches = [];

for( i=0; i < regex.length; i++ ) {
    if( RegExp(regex[i]).exec(str) ) {
        matches.push(RegExp(regex[i]).exec(str)[1]);
    } else {
        matches.push(undefined)
    }
}

console.log(matches);
```

Comment: what if `{ max-width : .8vw
}` :)

Comment: Thank you. Yeah, it looks like two regexes is the way to go. I'll stop trying to code golf it :) As for the @MichałDąbrowski's comment, something like `/min-width:\s*([0-9\.]+)(\w+)/` would work for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE** here is a working example. I used 2 regural expressions. First to find class or tag in CSS file/string, and the second regular expression is looking for property that you want.

```js
var fileCSS='.entry-meta {position: relative; top: 5px; left: 5px; font-size: 0.8em; line-height: 18px; color: #aaa; } .entry-footer { display: inline; color: white; margin: 0 2em; padding: 0; font-size: 0.8em; line-height: 18px; } div { MIN-width: 200px; display: block; max-width: 80% ; position: relative; background: rgba(255,255,255,0.05); padding-bottom: 20px; } img { width: 640px; min-width: 12vh ;height: auto; max-width: 800px; margin-bottom: 10px; }';

var properties = ['min-width', 'max-width'];

function pMatch(CSS, classOrTag, propertiesToFind) {
 var foundProperties=[]; var found=null;
 mainREGEX= new RegExp(classOrTag+"\\s*[{][()#\"'/\*a-z0-9\\s:%;*,.=-]*[}]", 'i');
 var found=CSS.match(mainREGEX)[0];
 if(found!==null) {
  for(a=0; a<propertiesToFind.length; a++) {
   propertyREGEX=new RegExp('('+propertiesToFind[a]+'\\s?:\\s?[0-9.]+[a-z%\\s]+).?;', 'i');
   var property=found.match(propertyREGEX);
   property?foundProperties.push(property[1]):foundProperties.push('undefined');
  }
 }
 return foundProperties;
}
console.log(pMatch(fileCSS, 'div', properties));
console.log(pMatch(fileCSS, '.entry-meta', properties));
console.log(pMatch(fileCSS, 'img', properties));
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Yes, that would be better for matching words. However, I've added an update explaining what I'm really going to be doing. Hmm...

Comment: I've updated the code. I used 2 regular expressions to be more precise.

Comment: Of course CSS needs to be valid, expressions are case insensitive and if you want the value only, you can use `property.split(':')[1]`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my answer is in python, but it should work the same in any language with lookarounds and backreferences.

The following code matched all three of your test-cases correctly, and I expect it to correctly match in virtually any case:

```
import re

strings = ["only screen and (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 599px)", "only screen and (min-width: 500px)", "(max-width: 599px)"]

regex = re.compile(r'(min|max)-width:\s*(\d+)px(.*(?!\1)(max|min)-width:\s*(\d+)px)?')
for string in strings:
    match = re.search(regex, string)
    print
    print string
    if match:
        term_1 = match.group(1)
        value_1 = match.group(2)
        term_2 = match.group(4)
        value_2 = match.group(5)
        print "Match!\n{} {}".format(term_1+"-width:", value_1)
        if term_2:
            print "{} {}".format(term_2+"-width:", value_2)
    else:
        print "Not a match"
```

When I ran it I got this output:

```
only screen and (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 599px)
Match!
min-width: 500
max-width: 599

only screen and (min-width: 500px)
Match!
min-width: 500

(max-width: 599px)
Match!
max-width: 599
```

The key idea is explained in Jason Cohen's answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator) question. He explained that the lookahead (or in this case the negative lookahead) means "match *expr* but after that continue matching at the original match-point."

In my example here, the lookahead checks to make sure it is not looking at the same string it matched at the beginning and then checks if, at that same point, there is a `max` or `min`. Note that after the first `px`, even the `.*` is enclosed in parentheses. This keeps it from behaving too greedily. Also, the entire second term is marked with the `?` so that the string will still match, even if a second occurrence is not found.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have another solution. It uses a `RegExp` to match the patterns and a `while` to stores the values:

```
function getMatches (str) {
    var reg = /(min|max)-width\s*:\s*(\d*\.?\d+)/g,
        ret = [undefined, undefined],
        arr;
    while ((arr = reg.exec(str)) !== null) {
        ret[+(arr[1] === "max")] = arr[2];
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/elchininet/bwg1onk6/