# Search file(readalltext) by passing two seperate parameters with regex

Tags: c#, regex

I am unable to get matched content inside a file with regex.
My requirement is user provide some text in textbox 1 and some text in textbox 2. 
The regex method should search the file by combination of both texts from textbox.
As of now I am able to find match with single search provided by user.

Here is the code:

```
private Regex R = null;

public void GetFileInfo(string textbox1val)
{
   if (this.R.IsMatch(text))
   {
      // my other code goes here....
   }
}

//on button click I am passing textbox text to regex and  to GetFileInfomethod
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
   this.R = new Regex(textbox1.Text);
   GetFileInfo(textbox1.Text);
}
```

Please help me on this question, thanks in advance for your help.

Regards,
Aditya.J

Comment: You have not included any requirements, nor described what is wrong with your code. Is the user defined text a regular epression or a literal text?

Comment: What is supposed to be in the text boxes, plain text or regular expressions?

Comment: Thank you all for your quick responses,  Wiktor Stribiżew user will be providing plane text and by the way Dmitry Egorov thanks for your solution this is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided the text boxes contain exact text to be searched for (as the textual description suggests) and not regular expressions (despite the code sample), your regex initialization may be either

```
this.R = new Regex(string.Format("{0}|{1}",
    Regex.Escape(textbox1.Text), Regex.Escape(textbox2.Text)));
```

if finding only one of the user provided strings is OK, or

```
this.R = new Regex(string.Format("^(?=.*{0})(?=.*{1})",
    Regex.Escape(textbox1.Text), Regex.Escape(textbox2.Text)));
```

if both of the user provided string should be found in the file.

Please notice the `Regex.Escape` to escape any regex special characters which a user may potentially type in.

The first regex is a simple [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html).

The second regex employs [positive lookbehinds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups) and the used construct is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389644/regex-to-match-string-containing-two-names-in-any-order).