# PCRE conditional statements not matching as expected

Tags: regex, pcre

Conditional pattern as described [here](https://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcrepattern.html#SEC21) doesnt seem to work

See my current [setup](https://regex101.com/r/oeWNxs/2)

I am trying to match any line that contains test and pie, any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: But `(?:(test)pie)` has no conditional construct in it. `(?:(test)pie)` = `testpie`. What is the problem?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am trying to match for any line that contains both test and pie

Comment: `test.*pie|pie.*test` or `^(?=.*test)(?=.*pie).*`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex to match string containing two names in any order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389644/regex-to-match-string-containing-two-names-in-any-order)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your answers were the correct one my thought process was to make a regexp where the first condition would match `test` and the then would try to match `pie` but I guess this was the wrong approach.

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that you might be trying to design some expression that might look like:

```
(?(exp)(?P<exp>)\btest\b|(?P<fruits>)\bpie\b)
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/XmW61N/1)

or

```
(?(1)(\btest\b)|(\bpie\b))
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/4T9di8/1)

---

> The expression is explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/4T9di8/1), if you wish to
>   explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/4T9di8/1debugger), you can watch how it
>   would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

Comment: It would be better to explain things in your own words, otherwise, somebody might think you're not making sense. Like for instance, unless this sequence `(?(exp)(?P<exp>)\btest\b|(?P<fruits>)\bpie\b)` is run inside a quantified group, `(?(exp))` is always false, and the _yes_ part is never matched. Also, even though PCRE, like Perl respects Pythons capture group naming convention, it's not the Perl like syntax.

Comment: `(?(1)(\btest\b)|(\bpie\b))` is what I was looking for, thanks. Is there any way to do this without a conditional?

Comment: @sp00kyb00g13 `(?(1)(\btest\b)|(\bpie\b))` is a pattern that is equal to `pie`. Why do you need such a strange pattern?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew after looking at it more that was not what I was looking for, it just matches for pie as you said.