# Filtering rows in pandas dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to filter rows in dataframe by multiple strings and I have searched and found this

```
search_values = ['vba','google']
df[df[0].str.contains('|'.join(search_values), case=False)]
```

But this I think based on finding either of the two strings `vba` or `google`. How can I join the both strings to be used `AND` not `OR`. I mean that the filter should be done if both the strings are there in the column so if this sentence for example `I mean vba will be with google in one sentence`. This row would be selected because it has both `vba` and `google`

Answer (score 1):

The [contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) function uses regex to find the rows that match the string. Using `|` is like `OR` in regex. If you want rows that contain both, this should work:

```
search_values = ['vba','google']
df[df[0].str.contains(f'{search_values[0]}.*{search_values[1]}|{search_values[1]}.*{search_values[0]}', case=False)]
```

The `.*` part means that any string can be found between the searched terms. So we try to find rows with `'vba'`, some string and then `'google'`, or rows with `'google'`, some string and then `'vba'`.

Comment: Amazing. Thanks a lot. How can I add more terms to the list search_values? Is there an easy way?

Comment: There are some other ways to do this that might be easier while searching for multiple terms. You can look at this question for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389644/regex-to-match-string-containing-two-names-in-any-order

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am lost in the link you posted.