# Regex to find if any of 3 words is in the line

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am needing to find whether the words root, name, or server are in a line with Regex so I can ignore them, but I have not found a good solution to identify them yet.

The format of what it would scan through is like this:

```
<Server name="JZL902757">
   <Snapshots timestamp="02/10/2022 12:16:31">
      <Snapshot root="D:\somefolder\anotherfolder">
```

All three words will always have a space preceding them and a "=" coming after.

I found this [Regex to match string containing two names in any order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389644/regex-to-match-string-containing-two-names-in-any-order) in trying to find a solution but it did not yield any matches when testing it.

Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Just `one|two|three`, right?

Comment: What you show looks like xml, so use a xml parser and check with xpath what element doesn't have an attribute "root", "name" or "server".

Comment: Try this: `\s(name|root|server)=`

Comment: Tags without any of these out-of-order attributes. Caveats apply `<[\w:]+(?=\s)(?!(?:[^>"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*?\s(?:root|name|server)\s*=\s*(?:"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|[^>]*?)*?>)\s+(?:"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|[^>]*?)+>` https://regex101.com/r/ZJKa2i/1

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to have understood what you want so I give you all the options.

This string will match any line containing one of the three words: server, string or name so it uses `|` for `OR`

```
^.*([Nn]ame|[Ss]erver|[Rr]oot).*$
```

This string will not match any line containing none of: server, string or name:
we have a negative look ahead for each one so it is `NOR`

```
^((?![Rr]oot)(?![Ss]erver)(?![Nn]ame).)*$
```

And this string will only match lines containing all three words, in any order, so it is `AND` using three positive look-aheads.

```
^(?=.*[Ss]erver)(?=.*[Rr]oot)(?=.* [Nn]ame).*$
```

and lastly this string will only match lines containing all three words, with a space before and an equals sign after each one

```
^(?=.* [Ss]erver=)(?=.* [Rr]oot=)(?=.* [Nn]ame=).*$
```