# Teradata search for two exact words in a string

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I am using regex to search for exact two words in any order. I got the first part of the search but the second part is not working.

REGEXP_SUBSTR('TWO WORDS ARE ONE','(?:^|\W)WORDS(?:$|\W') - one word search

how do I add one more word in the above search?

Comment: Why not just use like?  `column like '%WORD1%' and column like '%WORD2%'`

Comment: Do you need to extract the two strings? Possible duplicate of [regex to match string containing two names in any order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389644/regex-to-match-string-containing-two-names-in-any-order)