# Disallow three or more consecutive digits in a string containing certain letters and digits

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find a way to use RegEx to match strings that contain certain characters anywhere on the string. For instance, I want to match all the string that contain the letters `A`, `B` and `C`, and also the numbers `1`, `2` and `3`. They could be anywhere on the string, the letters could appear zero or more times, whereas the numbers can't appear 3 or more times in a row.

With these conditions, the strings `A3BC21`, `BBC11CC` and `AB22C31CCCAAA` would make a match but `111A`, `G05T` or `47ABC` wouldn't.

I don't even know where to start, because every RegEx I've seen follows the structure of the string you want to match, but I've never seen an example where the patterns you're looking for are anywhere on the string.

I have tried naïve things like this

```
^[ABC]+[123]{0,2}$
```

but this obviously won't return a match, since the letters have to appear first.

I have further tried capturing groups:

```
^([ABC]+|[123]{0,2})$
```

which either match strings with the letter pattern, or the number pattern, but not both.

And I've also tried positive lookaheads:

```
^[ABC]+(?=[123]{0,2})$
```

but of course, this doesn't work either. What can I do?

Comment: The value "BBC01CC" contains a "0" (zero), and the value "AB22C31CCDAAA" contains a "D". These are not legal values according to your criteria.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word) and [Regex to match string containing two names in any order](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4389644).

Comment: Something like [`^(?=.*[ABC])(?=.*[123])(?!.*([123])\1\1).+`](https://regex101.com/r/OkmSp1/1)?

Comment: If the letters, A|B|C, are optional then there is no reason to check for them? Are you also suggesting that at minimum one digit is required?

Comment: So you're real question is "I want to find an alphanumeric cluster with at least one of 1|2|3 but not more than 2 of them in a row.", right? So `1244444444325` should successfully match.

Comment: Sorry, the 0 and the D are typos, I'll correct them. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus not really, is not necessary that the numbers in the row are the same, just the fact that three numbers appear all together breaks the match; besides, only the numbers 1, 2 and 3 are valid. So, something like A12B33C11 is valid, but anything that contains: any letter that's not A, B or C, any number thats not 1, 2 and 3, and any row of numbers larger than 3, shouldn't return a match.

Comment: @InSync sorry, I don't understand how these would answer my question, I don't really see the search of certain characters in any position on the string.

Comment: It is unclear why `111A` should not match.

Comment: @Luuk it's because the numbers can't appear 3 or more times in a row. In that example, I have a row of three ones, which wouldn't fit the pattern.

Comment: Should there be AND at least a digit AND at least one of `A` `B` `C`  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
/^(?!.*\d{3})[ABC]*[123][ABC123]*$/gm
```

- `/^` - start delimiter, start line anchor
- `(?!.*\d{3})` - ensure that we don't have three or more digits in a row
- `[ABC]*[123][ABC123]*` - capture A, B, C, 1, 2, or 3 as many times as possible but ensure that 1, 2, or 3 appears one or more times
- `$` - end line anchor
- `/gm` - apply the global and multiline flags

https://regex101.com/r/Wq85Lu/1

Comment: I will remove my comments.

Answer (score 2):

Can you not just validate the entire expression for all legal characters, then check the max length of a sequence of digits? This would require two expression checks.

I would test for the following:

- Matches: `/^[ABC123]+$/`
- Does not match: `/\d{3}/g`

```js
const isValid = (s) => /^[ABC123]+$/.test(s) && !/\d{3}/g.test(s);

// All valid?
console.log(['A3BC21', 'BBC1CC', 'AB22C31CCAAA'].every(isValid));

// All invalid?
console.log(!['111A', 'G05T', '47ABC'].some(isValid));
```

Comment: @Thefourthbird you're right. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
^
  (?!.*           does not contain anywhere
    \d\d\d        three digits is a row
  )
  [ABC123]+       consists of ABC123
$
```

```
/^(?!.*\d\d\d)[ABC123]+$/
```

Answer (score 0):

this probably shouldn't be a single regular expression

a regex expression can identify non-matches (has non-allowed characters)

this also covers the A,B,C zero or more times

now you are down to the numbers showing...

if you sketch the permutations for one, two and three occurrences on each digit, you'll see that any expression you can dream up that might work will be hard to maintain and will probably have runtime performance issues -- i.e. a regex probably doesn't make sense

instead count the number of times "1" appears, if in [1,3], then continue for 2, then for 3