# Modifying this regex to match img src, alt and title in any order

Tags: php, html, regex, parsing, html-parsing

I have this regex to match image `src` tags and also `alt` or `title` tags, but it works only if the src is first, how should I modify it to match these 3 in any order ?
Or are there more accurate ways to do this by parsing html elements ? I assume by regex I might get back array elements but without knowing which is what.

For example now it matches:

```
img src="landscape.jpg" title="My landscape"
```

but not

```
img title="My landscape" src="landscape.jpg"
```

current regex is:

```
preg_match_all('#<img\s+[^>]*src="([^"]*)"(?:\s+[^>]*(?:alt|title)="([^"]+)")?[^>]*>#is', $url_contents, $image_matches);
```

Comment: Obligatory link: [You can't parse \[X\]HTML with regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454)

Comment: Other from that, this is a duplicate of [Regex to match string containing two names in any order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389644/regex-to-match-string-containing-two-names-in-any-order).

Comment: If you do this like in the answers from the question that @InSync mentions and you want to get all three attributes in any order with two being optional you can wrap two *capturing groups* into *lookaheads* inside *optional* groups and normally match the `src`. Something like [this regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/RfVW5B/1). Theses regexes are usually not efficient or html compliant, also they quickly grow big. That's why html parsers are recommended which can do that better.

Comment: Also see → [How to extract img src, title and alt from html using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138313/how-to-extract-img-src-title-and-alt-from-html-using-php)

Comment: InSync , @bobblebubble thanks, I ended up using DOMDocument instead (I posted an answer to my own question), seems way better than regex for this :D

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
(?<=<img)(?: (src|title|alt)="([^"]+)")?(?: (src|title|alt)="([^"]+)")?(?: (src|title|alt)="([^"]+)")?
```

- `(?<=<img)` - behind me is an `<img` start tag
- `(?: (src|title|alt)="([^"]+)")?` - look for a src, title, or alt attribute followed by its value and place them into capture groups
- `(?: (src|title|alt)="([^"]+)")?` - again
- `(?: (src|title|alt)="([^"]+)")?` - again

https://regex101.com/r/GXyAZf/1

Answer (score 1):

I found a [simple example using DOMDocument](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-extract-img-src-and-alt-from-html-using-php/):
It does just what I wanted and seems way more reliable than what I tried by regex.

```
<?php

$dom = new DOMDocument();
      
// Loading HTML content in $dom
@$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
  
// Selecting all image i.e. img tag object
$anchors = $dom -> getElementsByTagName('img');
  
// Extracting attribute from each object
foreach ($anchors as $element) {
      
    // Extracting value of src attribute of
    // the current image object
    $src = $element -> getAttribute('src');
      
    // Extracting value of alt attribute of
    // the current image object
    $alt = $element -> getAttribute('alt');
      
    // Extracting value of height attribute
    // of the current image object
    $height = $element -> getAttribute('height');
      
    // Extracting value of width attribute of
    // the current image object
    $width = $element -> getAttribute('width');
      
    // Given Output as image with extracted attribute,
    // you can print value of those attributes also
    echo '<img src="'.$src.'" alt="'.$alt.'" height="'. $height.'" width="'.$width.'"/>';
}
    
?>
```