# MySQL SELECT LIKE or REGEXP to match multiple words in one record

Tags: mysql, regex, select, sql-like

The field `table`.`name` contains 'Stylus Photo 2100' and with the following query

```
SELECT `name` FROM `table` WHERE `name` LIKE '%Stylus 2100%'
```

I get no results. Of course i would if i searched

```
SELECT `name` FROM `table` WHERE `name` LIKE '%Photo 2100%'
```

How can I select the record by searching 'Stylus 2100' ?

Thanks

Comment: _Caveat_:  This Question is about two words occurring in a particular order.  Most of the Answers do not allow for matching "2100 Stylus".

Comment: If one of two ( or many) options, try `select * from table1 where column1 REGEXP 'something|otherthing';`

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Well if you know the order of your words.. you can use:

```
SELECT `name` FROM `table` WHERE `name` REGEXP 'Stylus.+2100'
```

Also you can use:

```
SELECT `name` FROM `table` WHERE `name` LIKE '%Stylus%' AND `name` LIKE '%2100%'
```

Comment: Thanks, this way i won't get 'HP Laserjet 2100'. Sorry if my example was not the best.

Comment: One of the repliers to the answer here compared LIKE / REGEX performance and found that LIKE performed better, FYI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127088/mysql-like-in

Comment: @Amalgovinus thanks for the link, I wouldn't have thought so.. It's good to know :)

Comment: What if I have 3 words ?

Comment: @Florin in the first query `.+` indicate any character (1 or more) between Stylus and 2100 if you want to add EPSON it would be `EPSON.+'Stylus.+2100` in the second query you just need to add a new `AND` in the WHERE clause

Comment: Thanks @SERPRO. I know and I had tried ...but I am not getting the right result. But ... even with Stylus.+2100  I am not getting the right results ... with ^(.+EPSON.+2100.+)|^(.+2100.+EPSON.+).*$ I am geting the right LIKE results.

Comment: @Florin See these examples http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/53dbec0/1/0 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/53dbec0/2/0

Comment: why not `WHERE name LIKE '%Stylus%2100%'`?

Comment: The first requires Stylus to come before 2100; the second lets them be in either order.  So, they are "different" answers.

Comment: What about `SELECT name FROM table WHERE name REGEXP 'stylus|2100|photo'`

Comment: SELECT `name` FROM `table` WHERE `name` RLIKE 'Stylus|2100'

Answer (score 30):

I think that the best solution would be to use Regular expressions. It's cleanest and probably the most effective. Regular Expressions are supported in all commonly used DB engines.

In MySql there is `RLIKE` operator so your query would be something like:
<del>`SELECT * FROM buckets WHERE bucketname RLIKE 'Stylus|2100'`</del>
I'm not very strong in regexp so I hope the expression is ok.

**Edit**
The RegExp should rather be:

```
SELECT * FROM buckets WHERE bucketname RLIKE '(?=.*Stylus)(?=.*2100)'
```

More on MySql regexp support:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp

Comment: This regular expression does something different: it gets anything that contains _either_ 'Stylus' or '2100', not necessarily both.

Comment: I've improved my RegExp

Comment: I was searching for a regexp only solution and this trick did it ^^,

Comment: By adding a `|` between the 2 () like this `RLIKE '(?=.*Stylus)|(?=.*2100)'` will give separate results -->> rows with Stylus only, rows with 2100 only OR rows with both... but not necessarily the 2 in the same row...

Comment: Did you try this? Never heard that MySql regex supports lookarounds.

Comment: @bobblebubble - Good point; I think MySQL 8.0 and MariaDB 10.0 are when they got 'lookarounds' and lots of other esoteric regexps.

Answer (score 18):

You can just replace each space with `%`

```
SELECT `name` FROM `table` WHERE `name` LIKE '%Stylus%2100%'
```

Comment: Thanks but this way i wouldn't get if i searched 'Photo Stylus 2100'

Comment: haha! okay, that requirement was not specified on the question, "How can I select the record by searching 'Stylus 2100' ?"

Comment: I know this question is old, but is this not the most efficient solution? From what I can tell, this will match `Photo Stylus 2100`. It will match `anything` followed by `Stylus` followed by `anything` followed by `2100` followed by `anything`. If someone disagrees, please tell me why because it means I've fundamentally misunderstood something about like expressions.

Comment: @RTF I'm a bit late, but % is like + in Regex, not *. It matches _something_, not _anything_, so won't match `Photo Stylus 2100` but would match `Photo Stylus 2100x`.

Comment: @tjbp - Wrong.  `LIKE's` `%` matches the empty string.  So it is essentially identical to `RLIKE's` `.*`.  Melvin's answer stands; Alessio first comment is wrong.  It is trivial to test:  `SELECT 'Photo Stylus 2100' LIKE '%Stylus%2100%';` returns `1` (meaning `true`).

Answer (score 8):

The correct solution is a FullText Search (if you can use it) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html

This nearly does what you want:

```
SELECT * FROM buckets WHERE bucketname RLIKE '(Stylus|2100)+.*(Stylus|2100)+';

SELECT * FROM buckets WHERE bucketname RLIKE '(Stylus|2100|photo)+.*(Stylus|2100|photo)+.*(Stylus|2100|photo)+.*';
```

But this will also match "210021002100" which is not great.

Answer (score 1):

you need to do something like this,

```
SELECT * FROM buckets WHERE bucketname RLIKE 'Stylus.*2100';
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM buckets WHERE bucketname RLIKE '(Stylus)+.*(2100)+';
```

Comment: The second one gives allows the silly `StylusStylus 210021002100` -- Why have the `+`??

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your search is `stylus photo 2100`. Try the following example is using `RLIKE`.

```
SELECT * FROM `buckets` WHERE `bucketname` RLIKE REPLACE('stylus photo 2100', ' ', '+.*');
```

**EDIT**

Another way is to use `FULLTEXT` index on `bucketname` and `MATCH ... AGAINST` syntax in your `SELECT` statement. So to re-write the above example...

```
SELECT * FROM `buckets` WHERE MATCH(`bucketname`) AGAINST (REPLACE('stylus photo 2100', ' ', ','));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `name` FROM `table` WHERE `name` LIKE '%Stylus % 2100%'
```