# How search two or more words in string?

Tags: php, mysql, select

Hm, I think this will be an easy question but I can't find an answer to it.

I have a column called "name" in a mysql table.

A input might look like "How to programme 13".

I select it like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM lists WHERE name LIKE '%to programme 13%'"
```

This returns the row. But I want to be able to search for "how programme" or "how to 13". How can I search for this and make it return a result?

Thanks

Edit:

So basically I have to split the search string variable before searching?
I have a search string

```
$sw = $_GET['sw'];
"SELECT * FROM lists WHERE name LIKE '%".$sw."%'"
```

Comment: Your edit would not find "how to 13".

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM lists WHERE name LIKE '%programme%' AND name LIKE '%how%'
```

you can use REGEXP

```
 SELECT * FROM lists WHERE name REGEXP 'programme.+how'
```

Here you have a similar question: [MySQL SELECT LIKE or REGEXP to match multiple words in one record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9099469/mysql-select-like-or-regexp-to-match-multiple-words-in-one-record)

Comment: Why a -1 :( I'm so sad.

Comment: Because `SELECT * FROM lists WHERE name LIKE '%how programme%' AND name LIKE '%how to 13%' `, certainly does not work in this case and returns empty

Comment: HYPER FUNNY! and what about your answer, that means SELECT * FROM lists WHERE name LIKE '%programme%' AND name LIKE '%how%' this is incorrect too?

Comment: She's right Ali, why -1 for  my regex approach.

Comment: I down vote her before she post regex, and as you must know, the first query returns empty row, because there is no row with `how programme` in it

Comment: I assumed u dinged me too...

Comment: Elena change and to or.   Your query still would fail

Comment: The input "how to programmer 13" does not contain " how to 13" so the 2nd and like would fail the query

Comment: +1 for changing your mind

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT * from lists where name REGEXP 'how|program|13'
```

Answer (score 0):

simple repeat condition with **OR**

```
SELECT * FROM lists 
WHERE name LIKE '%how programme%'
  OR  name LIKE '%how to 13%'
```

Answer (score -1):

This query, searches for rows that have `programme` ***AND*** `how`

```
SELECT * FROM lists WHERE name LIKE '%programme%' AND name LIKE '%how%'
```

Comment: Mr Downvoter! can you say what I missed ?

Comment: Someone is in a stinky mood.  All of these answers work...