# How to use LIKE and wildcards in mysql statements

Tags: php, mysql, select, sql-like

I've researched this but couldn't find a solution for my specific problem.

I have a column containing data in a certain format. Here are some examples:

```
1
6
14
1;6;14;16
etc...
```

I need a mysql statement which for example it will select all columns where 16 occurs.

I've tried this but it's also selecting columns where 1 and 6 occur:

```
"SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE kategorien LIKE '%".$_GET['katid']."%' AND status = 1 ORDER BY pos ASC"
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Try using REGEXP in mysql

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL SELECT LIKE or REGEXP to match multiple words in one record](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9099469/mysql-select-like-or-regexp-to-match-multiple-words-in-one-record)

Comment: This is an example of bad database design. You should have an extra table for the data in this column.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but more important: Never use $_GET variables directly in SQL query, always escape them properly to prevent malicious input. See [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use MySQL function [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE
  FIND_IN_SET('16', REPLACE(kategorien, ';', ','))>0
```

however, it is usually not a good idea to store comma separated values in a single field, please have a look at this question: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating a helper function like this:

```
// Helper function
function getLike($str, $deliminator = ';', $field = 'kategorien') {
    if (false !== strpos($str, $deliminator)) {
        $strParts = explode($deliminator, $str);
        return "($field LIKE '%". implode("%' OR $field LIKE '%", $strParts) . "%')";
    } else {
        return "$field LIKE '%$str%'";
    }
}

// Debug
var_dump(getLike('1;6;14;16'));
```

Outputs:

```
string '(kategorien LIKE '%1%' OR kategorien LIKE '%6%' OR kategorien LIKE '%14%' OR kategorien LIKE '%16%')' (length=100)
```

In your query, you'd use it like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE ". getLike($_GET['katid']) ." AND status = 1 ORDER BY pos ASC"
```