# what does this like expression do in a MySQL query? "%Youth%club%"

Tags: mysql, regex

I know how the following work

1) `select description from mytable where description LIKE "club%"`
It matches rows where description has `club` keyword followed by `anything` e.g. clubbing or club sport

2) `select description from mytable where description LIKE "%club"`
It matches rows where description has `club` keyword at the end of `anything` e.g. cricket-club

3) `select description from mytable where description LIKE "%club%"`
It matches rows where description has `club` keyword anywhere e.g. cricketclubdog

However, I'm working on a piece of code from another developer which uses expression like

`select description from mytable where description LIKE "%youth%club%"`

Does anyone know what it is supposed to match? I found one answer here at stackoverflow but it doesn't describe much - https://stackoverflow.com/a/9099684/87596

Comment: The `%` wildcard applies in the same way, just between them. So it would match `youth oriented tennis clubs` for example. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

Comment: % stands for any character or characters,so you do the math

Comment: % matches any number of characters, even zero characters. cf [doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)

Answer (score 1):

`%` always matches whatever, so `%Youth%club%` will match any text that has Youth followed by club and there may or may not be something before, in between or after.

For example it would match:

> Youthclub
>   Youth tennis club
>   Primary Youth club for Texas

but not

> club for Youth

Comment: but it wouldn't match "clubs oriented tennis youth" ??

Comment: @TigerTiger No, the matches have to happen in the order they are written so it wouldn't match that.

Answer (score 0):

`%` is a wildcard - it will match any series of characters, including the empty string.  So the query:

```
select description 
from mytable 
where description LIKE "%youth%club%"
```

Would return any record where the words "youth" and "club" (in that order) appeared in the `description` field.