# Can you allow a regex match in a MySQL Select statement?

Tags: c#, mysql, regex

Ok, so generally, when searching for a substring in a table, you can search for something similar using wildcards; i.e. `'%abc%' will return *anything* that contains that substring ('abc').

However, if I'm looking for a specific format (perhaps "abc123") can I use a regex match to search for the additional string data? Eg:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [tbl] WHERE [name] LIKE @Param;";

Regex r = "\d*";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param", "abc" + r);
```

This would then check all of your strings, and depending on the regex, it would compare the strings:

- 'abc123' - Match
- 'abcd123' - No match

---

**Post note:** I'm not really looking so much into the syntax of the regex right now, I'm more interested to know whether or not this kind of process is *possible*.

Comment: I think you can just use `=`, unless I am missing some nuance in your question.  More importantly, why are you using SQL Server syntax on a question tagged "mysql" and asking about functionality not present in SQL Server?

Comment: @Gordon this has nothing to do with SQL, this is specifically about MySQL. However, this is also very generalised in terms of syntax, even though SQL and MySQL *do* share similar syntax anyway.

Comment: Look for REGEXP LIKE - MySQL supports it. The regex flavor is POSIX regex.

Comment: There is no standard SQL syntax for Regex, if a provider supports it, you will have to use provider specific syntax.

Comment: Have you checked this? - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL supports pattern matching operation based on regular expressions and the REGEXP operator.

```
SELECT name FROM person_tbl WHERE name REGEXP '^st';
```

You can have a look on the [MySQL SELECT LIKE or REGEXP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9099540/3796048)