# Make MySQL full text search to use AND

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

I've tried for ages to make this work the way I want, but I keep failing.

I have a table with 4 columns. The second one ("itemname") is the one that should be searched. The values contain special characters like "/" and "(".

**The working part:** Special characters are being ignored, the right entry gets matched.

**The non-working part:** It's between tons of other matches, that I **dont** need.

My query:

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT itemname, itemprice, itemupdate, itemstat
         FROM pricedata 
         WHERE MATCH itemname AGAINST ('%" . $search . "%' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
         ORDER BY itemprice DESC LIMIT 15");
```

**Example:**
I need to find an item with the value "M4A1-S / Hyper Beast (Factory New)".

---

Search for: "**M4A1-S Hyper**"

---

1. "**M4A1-S** / **Hyper** Beast (Factory New)"

   - *(RIGHT / both words match)*
2. "**M4A1-S** / Golden Coil (Factory New)"

   - *(WRONG / only one word matches)*
3. "AWP / **Hyper** Beast (Factory New)"

   - *(WRONG / only one word matches)*

---

Basically: Every word in the search bar should be treated with an "AND" and not an "OR".

I tried to find the solution myself, but I just can't make it work.

**Thanks a lot in advance! :)**

EDIT: New suggested query gives no results:

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT itemname, itemprice, itemupdate, itemstat  
FROM pricedata  
WHERE itemname REGEXP '%" . $search . "%'  
ORDER BY itemprice DESC LIMIT 15");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Regular expression

[try this site to understand regex](http://regexr.com/)

**'M4A1-S.+Hyper'** - matches two words 'M4A1-S' being first word
                      'Hyper' being the second

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT itemname, itemprice, itemupdate, itemstat
         FROM pricedata 
         WHERE itemname REGEXP 'M4A1-S.+Hyper'
         ORDER BY itemprice DESC LIMIT 15");
```

source: [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9099540/3202287)

Comment: Hey and thank you!   I tried to change it, but now it doesn't match ANY entry! Check my "new" query above!

Comment: Okay, i didn't see the "source" link at first. The problem is, that I need to use a search field and not a specific string. I am new to this and I am sorry for not understanding what I need to change... :(