# How to find specified string from database, which is stored as a JSON string using query?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a query to search specific results.

suppose I have a database field, let's say `category`, in this field data is stored as a JSON object.

e.g.

```
({"Facebook":1,"Gmail":0,"LinkedIn":0,"Social":0,"Event":0,"Other":0})
```

Now I want a query for filtering the data based on this category.

Let say I want to search the data which contains *Facebook:1* and *Social:1*

So how can I make a query for filtering the data?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23720988/how-to-filter-json-data-in-javascript-or-jquery

Comment: Would be better if you had a `social_category` table and `linked_social` which the above table links to. Then you just need to go the other way and select on `social_category` and join the rows. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)

Comment: Yeah I know, if there are two tables than it's very easy for me, but in my case I can't change our big database structure at this stage. I really appreciate your suggestion @Lawrence Cherone

Comment: many to many is 3 tables..

Comment: I must need to do this task as I have just database table which has multiple records with different json strings such as

row #1 : {"Facebook":1,"Gmail":0,"LinkedIn":0,"Social":0,"Event":0,"Other":0}
row #2 :{"Facebook":1,"Gmail":0,"LinkedIn":1,"Social":0,"Event":0,"Other":0}
row #3 :{"Facebook":0,"Gmail":1,"LinkedIn":0,"Social":1,"Event":0,"Other":0}
row #4 :{"Facebook":0,"Gmail":0,"LinkedIn":0,"Social":0,"Event":0,"Other":1}


Now I want to filter that row which contains the category boolean value 1 for Facebook and Gmail.

So ultimately I want row #1,2,3 as a result set.

Answer (score 0):

Having another table (as Lawrence mentioned in comment) is the usual way to go. But if you must use the current format, then you can have a **like** query with regx, if they sequence of the social networks is fixed then the query will be simpler. This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9099469/mysql-select-like-or-regexp-to-match-multiple-words-in-one-record) has some examples.

**Update**: If your set of categories are fixed and in same sequence as you mentioned in comment, then you don't even need to use like or regex. You can do an exact string match.

Use a function like following to get the string to match-

```
function getCategoryString($facebook = 0, $gmail =0, $linkedIn = 0, $social=0, $event=0, $other=0) 
{
    $qry = "({\"Facebook\":".$facebook.",\"Gmail\":".$gmail.",\"LinkedIn\":".$linkedIn.",\"Social\":".$social.",\"Event\":".$event.",\"Other\":".$other."})";
    return $qry;
}
```

and then use that string in the query-

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `category` = ".getCategoryString(1,1,0,0,0,0)
```

Note that tou'll have to modify this to escape the categoryString properly. I don't work in php so not sure what functions are used to escape mysql queries in php.

Comment: Yes, As I put the field value as {"Facebook":1,"Gmail":0,"LinkedIn":0,"Social":0,"Event":0,"Other":0},

So this parameters are fixed, in future it will never change. So I cannot make a seperate table for storing this static values.