# MySQL like search with non sequence words on a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called 'products' where i have product names like 'Iphone5 with 1GB Data', 'Iphone5 with 10GB Data', etc... and so on...

When user use a search box to search this products i make a query like the following...

```
 select *
 from products
 where product_name like '%USER_SEARCH_KEY%'
 limit 5;
```

now when i search 'iphone5 with' i get the rows which has 'iphone5 with' word in it. but when i search 'iphone5 1gb' i get no records found... i had to enter 'iphone5 with 1gb' to get that result. Is there any way i get the record on result set when i search for 'iphone5 1gb' keyword also ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look into **full text search**

Comment: check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9099469/mysql-select-like-or-regexp-to-match-multiple-words-in-one-record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 way for a solution to this task:

1. You can create [full-text index and search by it](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html)
2. You can break a user search query on words and make database query like the following:

   **`SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_name LIKE '%iphone5%1gb%' limit 5`**
3. You can use a search engine, for example, Elastic Search. I think this way is better

Answer (score 0):

you can use just 1gb in search string

```
 select * from t1 where  item like '%1GB%'
```

otherwise you have to use fulltext search but for using this to have to implement that in your table