# Match regex that contains multiple words

Tags: mysql, regex

What method should I use in MySQL to match two or more strings with a column?

I have a column `string` which contains keywords such as `apple`, `orange`, and `lemon`. What I need to have is to search rows that contains `apple` and `orange` using regex, the command has something like this:

```
where string regexp '(apple|orange)' and fruit = 1
```

The command above will break the rule, if a row with fruit `1` has only `apple` it should be not included in the result because fruit `1` didn't have another row which contains `orange`.

Comment: Did you really means "another _row_ which contains 'orange'"?  Perhaps you are asking whether the _same_ column `string` also contains 'orange'?  Example:  "We have apples and oranges." should match, but "I bought only apples." should not??

Comment: I am voting to reopen because the [_"dup" Question_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9099469/mysql-select-like-or-regexp-to-match-multiple-words-in-one-record) does not address matching "orange and apple".  That is, it focuses on "apple" followed by "orange".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to succeed when (and only when) `string` contains both "apple" and "orange", then the best way is to have `FULLTEXT(string)`

```
WHERE MATCH(string) AGAINST("+apple +orange" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

This will also match "ORANGE colored apples" and a few other variants.  Fulltext has some caveats, such as dealing only with "words" and not dealing with short words.  But if the restrictions are OK, this will be much faster than `LIKE` or `REGEXP`.

If Fulltext will not work, then something like this is best:

```
WHERE string LIKE '%apple%'
  AND string LIKE '%orange%'
```

Or it can be done with `REGEXP`:

```
WHERE string REGEXP '(apple.*orange)|(orange.*apple)'
```

If you need to obey word boundaries and/or allow plurals, then add that to your specification; these suggested solutions may need changing.  For example, changing `.*` to `.+` would reject "appleorange" while still allowing "apple/orange".