# R: selecting element from list

Tags: r

I have two elements:

```
id1 <- "dog"
id2 <- "cat"
```

I want to extract any combination of these elements (dogcat or catddog) from a vector

```
L <- c("gdoaaa","gdobbb","gfoaaa","ghobbb","catdog")
L
```

I tried:

```
L[grep(paste(id1,id2,sep="")),L]
L[grep(paste(id2,id1,sep="")),L]
```

but this gives an error.

I would be grateful for your help in correcting the above.

Comment: `L[grep(paste(id1,id2,sep=""),L)]
L[grep(paste(id2,id1,sep=""),L)]`

Comment: A simple non-regex solution could be `grepl(id1, L) & grepl(id2, L)`. You can add `fixed = TRUE` to both if efficiency is important.

Comment: I don't understand it, but apparently `grepl("(dog(cat)?)", L)` works courtesy of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177081/mulitple-words-in-any-order-using-regex

Comment: That pattern matches `dogcat` but also `dog`, as in: `grepl("(dog(cat)?)", "dog")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is from misplaced parentheses, so these minor variations on your code will work.

```
L[grep(paste(id1,id2,sep=""), L)]
# character(0)
L[grep(paste(id2,id1,sep=""), L)]
# [1] "catdog"
```

Alternatively this is a regex one-liner:

```
L[grep(paste0(id2, id1, "|", id1, id2), L)]
# [1] "catdog"
```

That and some patterns in the comments will also match `dogcatt`. To avoid this you could use `^` and `$` like so:

```
x <- c("dogcat", "foo", "catdog", "ddogcatt")
x[grep(paste0("^", id2, id1, "|", id1, id2, "$"), x)]
# [1] "dogcat" "catdog"
```