# Match a list of possible words in a string in any order

Tags: python, regex

I know this question sounds similar to others, but see my notes below on those solutions.

I need a regex to use in Python to search for specific words in any order in a string. What I want to do is put brackets around the series of words.

Here is my example text:

> apples, pears, bananas are fruit
>
> pears, apples, and bananas are in the fruit basket
>
> you can use bananas, pears, and apples in a fruit salad
>
> he also likes pears, bananas, and apples for a snack
>
> she likes cheese for a snack but also apples or pears

Ultimately, I want to be able to put brackets around the fruit series, like so:

> [apples, pears, bananas] are fruit
>
> [pears, apples, and bananas] are in the fruit basket
>
> you can use [bananas, pears, and apples] in a fruit salad
>
> he also likes [pears, bananas, and apples] for a snack
>
> she likes cheese for a snack but also [apples or pears]

In doing my research, I found the following posts:

[Multiple words in any order using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177081/multiple-words-in-any-order-using-regex)

This solution did nothing when I tested it in Regex101.

[Regex to match string containing two names in any order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389644/regex-to-match-string-containing-two-names-in-any-order)

This solution is very similar to the first and did not work either.

[Regex to match multiple words in any order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43346897/regex-to-match-multiple-words-in-any-order)

This solution came the closest to working with some slight modification:

```
(APPLES|BANANAS|PEARS) \[\1]\
```

However, this puts brackets around each fruit listed rather than around the series:

> [apples], [pears], [bananas] are fruit

I'm obviously missing something, so I would appreciate whatever help someone could give me.

Thanks!

Comment: `(?i)\b(?:APPLES|BANANAS|PEARS)\b(?:\s*(?:,\s*)?(?:(?:or|and)\s+)?(?:APPLES|BANANAS|PEARS))*\b` and replace with `[\g<0>]`, see https://regex101.com/r/RKv9ci/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this regex for search using case insensitive switch:

```sh
\b(?:apples|pears|bananas)(?:(?:\s+(?:or|and)\s+|\s*,\s*)+(?:apples|pears|bananas)\b)*
```

and replace this with: `[\g<0>]`

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0IoNpb/1)

**Code:**

```sh
import re

regex = r"\b(?:apples|pears|bananas)(?:(?:\s+(?:or|and)\s+|\s*,\s*)+(?:apples|pears|bananas))*"

subst = r"[\g<0>]"

result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.IGNORECASE)
```